# Relationship between Minkowski distance and Minkowski space

Tags: metric-spaces, physics

The metric induced by the p-norm:

$d((x_1,\dotsc,x_n),(y_1,\dotsc,y_n)) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i-y_i|^p\right)^{1/p}$

is often called the Minkowski distance.

There is also Minkowski space, which as I understand is a bit like Euclidean 4-space.  And there is the Minkowski metric tensor defined for it.

Is there a relationship between Minkowski distance and the Minkowski metric tensor?  If not, why is the metric induced by the p-norm called Minkowski distance?  Does anybody have a reference for this name?

Comment: Isn't the relationship just [Hermann Minkowski](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermann_Minkowski)?

Comment: @martini Well, that's what I assumed, but what has Minkowski got to do with the metric which I mentioned?  Basically I'm looking for a better source for the name and origin of this metric than Wikipedia.  I thought the origin might have been from the metric tensor, but apparently not.

Comment: @Borbus, why did you said you think is like the euclidean 4-space? isn't it more like euclidean n-space?

Answer (score 6):

No. The Minkowski metric tensor is actually based on a very different metric:
$$d((x_1,...x_n),(y_1,...,y_n))=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{(x_i-y_i)^2}- (x_n-y_n)^2$$
Which in fact is not really a metric, since $d$ can be smaller than zero (if you want to be formal - this is a [pseudo-Riemannian manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-Riemannian_metric))

Comment: Ok, that's what I thought the metric tensor looked like, or it can be +--- apparently (where time is the first component).  It's still a mystery to me why the metric I mentioned is named after Minkowski in that case.

Comment: As @martini pointed out, they are both named after the same person - that's it.

Comment: Not quite. The correct formula is $d((x_1,...x_n),(y_1,...,y_n))=\sqrt{ |\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}{(x_i-y_i)^2}- (x_n-y_n)^2|}$ and it is a pseudo-distance. By abuse, though, it is still called "metric".